# Аналог OllyDbg под ubuntu (x64)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ассемблер, отладка, поиск-программ

Господа,

я как то интересовался, и находил отладчик, который функционально похож на OllyDbg. И работает в консоли под ubuntu. А сейчас попробовал его найти второй раз - и не получилось. Не подскажете ли, что это за штука?

Я помню, что у него был такой "турбо-вижн интерфейс" - с прсевдо - окошками в консоли.

Функционально хотелось бы всё время видеть регистры процессора и декомпилированный код в виде asm'а. В идеале - 64 битный отладкчик, но если такого нет - хоть что нибудь.

Отлаживать надо ELF файлы.

В попытках вспомнить я уже перебрал ddd, какие то оболочки для dbg, но так и не нашел.

Спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: Можно [Cutter](https://cutter.re) попробовать, туда недавно возможность отладки завезли (не пробовал, отладка возможно еще сырая (beta)).

Comment: @insolor - я посмотрел - да, cutter выглядит интересно, но точно не тот, который я находил когда то :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая штука, как `edb` под линукс, по сути тот же `gdb`, только менее хардкорный. Рекомендую.

Comment: Спасибо! похоже, edb решил мои проблемы. он не консольный, но очень удобный

Comment: Спустя несколько месяцев я отметил этот ответ как "принятый". Несмотря на краткость, он подсказал мне именно тот дебаггер, котрым я реально смог пользоваться. В то же время, я ОЧЕНЬ благодарен авторам других ответов, котрые потратили время чтобы дать мне гораздо больше материала для размышлений. Парни, спасибо!

Comment: @S.H. Рада была помочь :)

Answer (score 5):

[GUI for a GNU Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671138/gui-for-a-gnu-debugger/10490633)

[gdbinit](https://github.com/gdbinit/Gdbinit)
[image: gdbinit]

[voltron](https://github.com/snarez/voltron)
[image: voltron]

[peda](https://github.com/longld/peda)
[image: peda]

Comment: огромное спасибо за  такой подробный отвкт!

Answer (score 5):

В линуксе есть немного странный, но мощный отладчик gdb. Как по мне, он сильно проще OllyDbg. И у него есть консольный ui, достаточно запустить с параметром `-tui`. Выглядит действительно как турбовижн интерфейс (в некоторых дистрибутивах может быть скомпилирован без поддержки этого).

В [документации есть команды](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html), как настроить, какие окошки показывать (да, да, можно и регистры включить)

Некоторые, так хорошо вычитывают документацию, что делают вот такие чудеса [gdb dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard). По факту - это просто один файл-конфиг. Но выглядит как старый добрый softice.

Можно посмотреть на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209534/how-to-highlight-and-color-gdb-output-during-interactive-debugging/17341335#17341335) и сделать себе нужный вид gdb.

---

Ещё есть [cgdb](https://cgdb.github.io/), но как по мне, то это обычный gdb -tui.

Answer (score 1):

[Online Disassembler](https://onlinedisassembler.com/static/home/index.html)

ODA - это онлайн-дизассемблер для широкого спектра машинных архитектур, включая: Alpha, ARM, AVR, Intel x86, Motorola 68000, MIPS, PDP-11, PowerPC, SPARC, Z80 и многие другие....
онлайн-сервис, когда у вас нет времени, ресурсов или требований для использования более тяжелой альтернатив

Comment: Привет, спасибо большое, всегда интересно прочитать про такие штуки.